# Sqoop Import from Mysql DB is taking Huge time to Complete

Tags: import, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to import some 5 records from a MySQL table "employees" and import it to hdfs by creating a hive table in Sqoop Import command. But the query is running for a long time and I am unable to see any result.

I have started Hadoop services and it is up and running. I can create tables in Hive manually also.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBName 
  --username UserID --password Pwd --split-by EMPLOYEE_ID 
  -e "select EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID <=105 and $CONDITIONS" 
  --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/mysqldb.db/employees 
  --fields-terminated-by ","   
  --hive-import  
  --create-hive-table 
  --hive-table mysqldb.employees -m2
```

What is going on here?

Sqoop Query  ->
[image: Scoop Query]

URL ->
[image: URL]

Comment: _...waiting for AM container to be allocated..._ Something is not right with your YARN configuration, as ResourceManager can't allocate a container to run ApplicationMaster.

Comment: thanks....it was the issue with Yarn Node Manager with below permission issue ......
Permissions incorrectly set for dir /tmp/hadoop-samsh/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-xr-x, actual value = rwxrwxr-x